# Help understanding the meaning of this definition of a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

In paper I am currently reading, the following passage appears:

> Given a prior random variable $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$, we
> denote the probability density function (PDF) by $\pi_{X}(x),x \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

and later on:

> ...assume that an ensemble $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^N,i=1,...,M$ is given,
> which mathematically are considered as realizations
> $X_i(ω), ω \in \Omega$, of $M$ independent (or
> dependent) random variables $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ with
> law $\pi_X$.

I don't quite understand the interpretation of the random variable $X$ here. My intuition so far was that the random variable $X$ is, well, a *random* variable which can take on specific values $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with probability (density) $\pi_X(x)$. Is this interpretation correct (or complete)? What does the interpretation of $X$ as a map from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^N$ represent?

Unfortunately, the paper does not explain what $\Omega$ or $ω$ is, nor are any of these variables used later. Since it only plays a role in the definition, I assume it is something seemingly obvious enough that the authors did not bother to define it. Do you have any idea what the authors want to show here?

Comment: $\Omega$ is the space of possible events: $\{ \text {head}, \text {tail} \}$ and $\omega \in \Omega$ is an event

Comment: $\pi_X$ associates to any event a real number $r \in \mathbb R$ (in case $N=1$). $\pi_X( \text {head})=0.5$

Comment: $\Omega$ is the set of all possible outcomes $\omega$. $X(\omega)$ is the value (in $\Bbb{R}$) of the random variable $X$ when scenario $\omega$ happens, therefore $X$ is a function of $\Omega$ to the real numbers

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, $\Omega$ is not necessarily a vector space akin to $\mathbb{R}^N$? So the task of the random variable $X$ here is to assign a scalar or vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ to a certain event $w \in \Omega$ with probability (density) $\pi_X(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn my comments into an answer:

$\Omega$  is the (non-empty) set of all possible outcomes $\omega$. $X(\omega)$ is the value (in $\Bbb{R}$) of the random variable $X$ when scenario $\omega$ occurs, therefore $X$ is a function of $\Omega$ to the real numbers.

$X$ is a function that assigns a real value to an outcome. For example, $X$ could be the result of a coin flip, $\omega_1$ is the event of "heads", $\omega_2$ is the event of "tails". Define $$X=\begin{cases}0,\quad\text{if heads}\\1,\quad\text{if tails}\end{cases}$$Then $X(\omega_1)=0$ and $X(\omega_2)=1$. In this case $\Omega=\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}\stackrel{\frown}{=} \{\text{heads, tails}\}$.

Answer (score 2):

In probability, it's conventional to use the Greek letter $ω$ (omega) to denote an individual outcome in the set $Ω$ (Omega) of all possible outcomes, called the [*sample space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space). $\Omega$ itself is directly equipped with a $σ$-algebra, $\mathcal{F}$, of subsets called [*events*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(probability_theory)), and a [probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) $P$ on $\mathcal{F}$ that is [$σ$-additive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_additivity) and satisfies $P(Ω) = 1$, $P(∅) = 0$. Using this formalism, a random variable $X$ is conventionally defined as a [measurable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function) $X: \Omega \to S$ for some other [measure space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_space) $S$ (often, as here, $\Bbb{R}^n$).

While in many cases it's possible to let $\Omega = \Bbb{R}^n$ and define $P$ on subsets of $\Bbb{R}^n$ directly, sometimes this misses relationships between certain random variables that would be clunky to formalize alternatively. For example, suppose I'm playing the [St. Petersburg game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox#The_paradox) with a fair coin. My sample space $\Omega$ looks like this: $$\Omega = \{ T, HT, HHT, HHHT, ..., H^k T, ... \}$$ where $H^k T$ denotes a string of $k \geq 0$ heads, followed by a tail.

Two natural random variables to define on this sample space are the *stopping time* $N: \Omega \to \Bbb{R}$ given by $$N(H^k T) := k+1, k = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...$$ and the *winnings* $W: \Omega \to \Bbb{R}$ given by $$W(H^k T) := 2^{k+1}, k = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...$$ Clearly we should have $W = 2^N$, but if I consider $W$ and $N$ as functions from $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ (i.e. their sample space is $\Bbb{R}$), I have 2 different and incompatible probability mass functions $p_N$ and $p_W$ on the domain $\Bbb{R}$, and it's hard to make sense of the equation $W = 2^N$. If I let my sample space instead be the original sequence of coin flips in the game itself, this difficulty vanishes, as both $W$ and $N$ are functions of an individual sequence of coin flips and it's easy to formalize their relationship properly.